# Android + Verisign SSL Version 1

Tags: android, exception, ssl, verisign

I have the following problem: I use a Verisign SSL Cert and try to connect from my android app to my tomcat 7 server. In my opinion the cert is installed correctly as I can connect successfully with the same app for iphone, firefox browser and the ssl-tool of verisign and other ssl check tools.

But the android app says: java.security.cert.CertificateException: `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Version 1 certs can't be used as intermediate certificates`

I try to reorder the certificates as described in many answers and implemented the solution with the `EasySSLSocketFactory` and `EasyX509TrustManager` but I could not solve the exception. The Version 1 cert is ordered as last cert, so I have `[0]-my cert`, `[1]-intermediate1, [2]-intermediate2 and finally [3]-the root Version 1`. I don't want to allow all certs for security reasons. I am not sure about why this exception is thrown but it seems that either verisign is issueing the wrong root certificate or android has not implemented the root in its truststore. How could this be solved? Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and managed to solve it yesterday. You are correct in that the root certificate is not accepted, since it is a version 1 certificate.

I solved the problem by first figuring out which certificate in the certificate chain was the version 1 certificate (which causes the error) by using openssl.

```
simonevertsson$ openssl s_client -connect my.secure.site.com:443
```

This gives the certificate chain. Example:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=SE/ST=Uppsala/L=Uppsala/O=Example AB/CN=my.secure.site.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
```

I then went to the [VeriSign Root Certificate download page](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots) and  manually downloaded the .pem-file for the version 1 certificate, which in my case was the Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority.

When the certificate file had been downloaded I just followed the Android Developer guide on [Adding unknown CAs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa). And just like that, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed only one certificate on the web/app server. Remove all expired certificates.